# Perl: How to treat a certain MySQL table as utf8

Tags: mysql, perl, utf-8, cgi

Here is a system that handles everything in latin1, but I want this one particular table to be read as utf8, then properly encoded into JSON.

How do I switch the connection to utf8, then read it, then switch the connection back?

I know how to do the JSON, but the MySQL I do not know about.

I am using the DBI MySQL driver, and this is an old CGI program.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
$dbh->do('set names utf8');
```

Comment: How do you set it back when you are done? I need to follow my code up with a bunch of existing non-utf8 code.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey, `$dbh->do("set names 'latin1'");`

Answer (score 0):

you can change connection encoding like this:

```
$dbh->do("set names 'utf8';");

# ...do something with utf8 tables...

$dbh->do("set names 'latin1';");

# do something with latin1 tables

$dbh->disconnect;
```